# Azure Win Server 2012 Datacenter - Unable to complete installation of feature 'Media Foundation'

Tags: azure

I am facing several difficulties for installing the feature "Media Foundation" in a Win Server 2012 Datacenter. After we had installed it from Server Manager, during the reboot appears the message that en error occurs configuring the features and then starts a roll-back of the installation.  No additional info is provided.

In the CBS log I have found the following error entries:

> 2016-03-11 13:19:19, Error                 (F) Logged @2016/3/11:13:17:10.110 : [ml:96{48},l:94{47}]"MOF (install online) $(runtime.wbem)\mswmdm.mof"
>       [gle=0x80004005]
>       2016-03-11 13:19:19, Error                  (F) CMIADAPTER: Inner Error Message from AI HRESULT = 8004402f [Error,Facility=FACILITY_ITF,Code=16431 (0x402f)]
>       [
>       [206]"Parsing MOF file: C:\Windows\system32\wbem\mswmdm.mof
>       Error 80 in Function CMofLexer::CMofLexer line 614
>       C:\Windows\system32\wbem\mswmdm.mof (1): error SYNTAX 0X8004402f: Error creating temporary file

Any ideas or workaround about how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This can occur if WMI is unable to access the TEMP and/or TMP location, either because of permissions or because the path is invalid.